# bgSlider.js need to activate the slideshow

Tags: javascript, background, slider

Dear all I have the following BgSlider.js script and I've been struggling to make the background images rotate automatically rather than clicking on the pagination to move from one image to the other. Tried changing some of the options like slideshow=true and also tried changing the duration speed. Here is the code I'm working with:

```
$.extend(_fw.meth,{
bgSlider:{
        slideshow:false,
        duration:1500,
        easing:'',
        preload:false,
        pagination:true,
        pagActiveCl:'current',
        pagEv:'click',
        pagArea:'a',
        current:0,
        currN:0,
        method:'fit',
        altCSS:{},
        padding:0,
        preload:false,
        spinner:false,
        minSpinnerWait:150,
        preloadFu:function(){
            var opt=this,
                img=$('<img>')
                        .css({position:'absolute',left:'-999%'})
                        .appendTo('body'),
                num=opt.images.length
            ;(function(){
                if(num)
                    img .load(arguments.callee)
                        .attr({src:opt.images[--num]})
                else
                    img.remove()                    
            })()
        },
        pagsFu:function(){
            var opt=this,
                pags=opt.pags=$(opt.pagination+' li')
            if(!opt.images)
                opt.images=[],
                pags.each(function(i){
                    opt.images.push($('a',this).attr('href'))
                })
            pags.find(opt.pagArea).each(function(i){
                $(this).data({num:i})
            })
            pags.parent()
                .delegate(opt.pagination+':not(.'+opt.pagActiveCl+')'+(opt.pagArea?' '+opt.pagArea:''),opt.pagEv,function(){
                    var th=$(this)
                    opt.changeFu(th.data('num'))
                    opt.pags.not(th.parent().addClass(opt.pagActiveCl)).removeClass(opt.pagActiveCl)    ;
                    Cufon.replace('.pagination li', { fontFamily: 'Ubuntu', hover:true });
                    return false
                })
        },
        preFu:function(){
            var opt=this
            opt.img
                .css({
                    position:'absolute',
                    left:0,
                    top:0
                    })
                .css(opt.altCSS)
                .attr({src:opt.images[opt.current]})                    
            opt.img.each(function(){
                var _f=function(){
                            opt.resizeFu()
                            opt.img.data({width:opt.img.width(),height:opt.img.height()})                       
                        }
                if(this.complete)
                    _f()
                else
                    $(this)
                        .load(_f)
            })

            opt.holder
                .css({
                    position:'fixed',
                    left:0,
                    right:0,
                    top:0,
                    bottom:0,
                    zIndex:-1
                    })
                .append(opt.img)
            if(opt.spinner)
                opt.spinner.hide()
        },
        resizeFu:function(){
            var opt=this,
                img=opt.img,
                w=opt.wi,
                h=opt.he,
                l=img.css('left'),
                t=img.css('top'),
                bw=document.body.offsetWidth-opt.padding,
                bh=document.body.offsetHeight,
                k=w/h

        },
        changeFu:function(n){
            var opt=this
            if(n==opt.currN)
                return false
            opt.currN=n
            opt.showFu(opt.images[n])
        },
        nextFu:function(){
            var opt=this,
                n=opt.currN
            opt.changeFu(++n<opt.images.length?n:n=0)
            opt.pags.eq(n).addClass(opt.pagActiveCl).siblings().removeClass(opt.pagActiveCl)
        },
        prevFu:function(){
            var opt=this,
                n=opt.currN
            opt.changeFu(--n>=0?n:n=opt.images.length-1)
            opt.pags.eq(n).addClass(opt.pagActiveCl).siblings().removeClass(opt.pagActiveCl);
            Cufon.replace('.pagination li', { fontFamily: 'Ubuntu', hover:true });
        },
        showFu:function(src){
            var opt=this,
                clone=opt.clone=opt.img.clone(true)
            if(opt.slideshow)
                clearInterval(_timer[0])
            clone
                .css({
                     opacity:0,
                     left:0,
                     top:0
                     })
                .appendTo(opt.holder)   
                .width(opt.img.width())
                .load(function(){
                    var th=$(this)
                    opt.holder.find('>*').stop()                        
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        opt.spinner.hide()
                        opt.wi=th.width()
                        opt.he=th.height()
                        clone
                            .stop()
                            .animate({
                                    opacity:1
                                    },{
                                    duration:opt.duration,
                                    easing:opt.easing,
                                    complete:function(){
                                        var tmp=opt.holder.find('img')
                                        opt.img=$(this)
                                        tmp.not(tmp.last()).remove()
                                        opt.resizeFu()
                                    }
                                    })
                    },opt.minSpinnerWait)
                })
                .attr({src:src})
                opt.spinner.show()
                if(opt.slideshow)
                    _timer[0]=setInterval(function(){
                        opt.nextFu()
                    },opt.slideshow)
        },
        init:function(opt){
            var holder=opt.holder=this,
                img=opt.img=$('<img>')
            if(opt.pagination)
                opt.pagsFu()
            if(opt.spinner)
                opt.spinner=$(opt.spinner)
            opt.preFu()
            if(opt.preload)
                opt.preloadFu()
            window.onresize=function(){
                opt.resizeFu()
            }
            if(opt.slideshow)
                _timer[0]=setInterval(function(){
                    opt.nextFu()
                },opt.slideshow)
            holder.data({opt:opt})
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the transition make ​​Billboard images, you must modify a few lines of code:

1 - Declare SlideShow

```
$ ('# bgSlider'). bgSlider ({
/ / Other settings
slideshow: true,
interval: 24000,
/ / Other settings
```

2 - Modify the bgSlider.js

Search this code

```
if (opt.slideshow)
_timer [0] = setInterval (function () {
opt.nextFu ()
} opt.slideshowl)
```

And replace it with this:

```
if (opt.slideshow)
_timer [0] = setInterval (function () {
opt.nextFu ()
}, opt.interval) / / variable change opt.slideshow
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better way just use

```
slideshow: 10000 // Time in milliseconds
```

That's it!